# How do I install Java 12 on Mac OSX now that Java 13 is out?

Tags: java, homebrew, java-12

I cannot find Java 12 to install anymore, just Java 13. But Gradle does not support Java 13 yet, so I need to use 12 as an alternative for now. When I look in Homebrew using `brew search java` I find all sort of javas: Java 11, Java 6 (!) and Java, which used to be Java 12 but is now Java 13.

Any idea how I can get Java 12?

Comment: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_mac

Comment: Java 12 is [EOL](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html#JavaSESupport).

Comment: well eol or not I need it as java13 is not supported yet...

Comment: Java 13 will only be supported through March of 2020 - about 6 months.  Java 11 will be supported through at least September of 2022.  Be careful chasing the most recent release as you'll be dealing with a continuous stream of updates for Java and the tools around it.

Comment: I’m not very familiar with Gradle.  How can Gradle “not support Java 13 yet”?  What will Gradle do differently if your JDK version is 13 instead of 12?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Solution 1

You can get Java 12 from the [AdoptOpenJDK Homebrew tap](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk). (a tap is a formula repository) And the AdoptOpenJDK team maintains different versions of JDK in this repo.

```bash
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk12
```

[image]

#### Solution 2

`java` is a formula defined in the repo [Homebrew-cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/search?o=desc&q=java&s=committer-date&type=Commits). You can search and find the history file `java.rb` where Java 12 was defined within, and install Java 12 with the URL to that specific history file.

The following command installs vanilla OpenJDK (not the AdoptOpenJDK) 12.0.2.

```bash
brew cask install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/26203ad42b40c4bc3baa2f6cfa8469f1245b7fbc/Casks/java.rb
```

Comment: In addition to installing the JDKs listed here, you should also consider using a tool like JEnv https://www.jenv.be/ so you can more easily toggle between them at both a local and system-wide level. JEnv also lets to switch to other JDK releases too in case you need to use Coretto or even Oracle

Comment: `brew install cask adoptopenjdk12` as of 2021.

Comment: `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk12` as of 2022